# MVC ModelState became null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

```
  [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        
        public JsonResult EditPost(Expense model)
        { 
            SetLists();
            model.TravelLines = (List<ExpenseTravel>)Session["ExpenseTravelLines"];
            model.ExpenseLines = (List<ExpenseLine>)Session["ExpenseLines"];

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
               ...

                return Json(new { success = true, message = GlobalViewRes.UpdatedSuccessfully }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            return Json(new { success = false, message = GetErrorMessage(ModelState) }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);          
        }
```

This my js

```
$(".send-form.Travel").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    var obj = $("#formEdit").serializeToJSON();
    obj.ExpenseLines = data.ExpenseLines;
    var id= obj.Entry_No;
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Expense/EditPost',
        type: 'post',
        data: obj,...
```

I enter edit to correct the data I created. The part I made changes to the model is empty. I have defined a Session. It comes to the session, but does not enter the modelstate, the expenseline is empty.How can I fix it ?
Sorry for my English :)

Comment: Your `url` is incorrect. It should be: `url: '/Expense/Edit`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? You are posting your form to your action method and then overriding it with the `Session` value? What is your question? Are you getting no values in your `Expense` model? Or are you getting no values in your `Session` variable?

Comment: I can get values in  my session. but modelstate.valid became null and didnt enter the modelstate inside

Comment: Can you show your `Expense` model?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 var obj = $("#formEdit").serialize(); //or serializeToArray()
```

and remove  [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] while you are testing